# How can I instrument mocha and a code coverage tool with CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, code-coverage, istanbul

Istanbul seems great - seen lots of awesomeness there. Even `blanket` seems pretty cool. But none seem to play nice, and if they do, I can't figure out how to get it to play with `grunt` and if I can, I'm left with the problem of running `coffee-script`.

For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958736/coffeescript-mocha-blanket-how-to) gives a great example and it seems great, but no grunt! Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using one grunt library for that. It's called [Grunt Mocha Test](https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test).

It plays well when your mocha tests are for nodejs backend project. I hope my configuration helps you :

```
mochaTest:
  options:
    require:
      - 'coffee-script/register'
      - './test/mocha.coffee'
      - 'coverage/blanket'
    quiet: true
    reporter: 'html-cov'
    captureFile: 'coverage.html'
  src:
    - 'test/**/*.coffee'
```

The format for my grunt configuration files is in `yaml`, because I'm using another plugin that separates the tasks.

my `mocha.coffee` file looks something like this :

```
# Initialize Should for chai
global.chai = require 'chai'
global.chai.use require 'chai-as-promised'
global.chai.config.includeStack = true
global.should = chai.should()
```